Steps for classifying more than one singularity
Upon doing a lot of questions where I have to classify more than one singularity, I've come u with some steps to do based on patterns that I've seen. But, I'm unsure as to whether the steps I've created are accurate. I have searched around online, but there is not much information in regards to classifying 2 singularities.
Here is what I've theorised:
Let's say $f(z)$ has 2 singularities that we want to classify

Split $f(z)$ into 2 functions $g(z)$ and $h(z)$ where these functions each contain one of the singularities respectively.

Classify the singularity in $g(z)$ and classify the singularity in $h(z)$.

This is what the singularities are classified as in $f(z)$.


Here is an example to demonstrate:

Find and classify the singularities of $f(z) =\frac{\sin(z)}{2z^3+z^4}$

$f(z) =\frac{\sin(z)}{2z^3+z^4}=\frac{\sin(z)}{z^3(2+z)}=\frac{sin(z)}{z^3}\cdot \frac{1}{(2+z)}$
Classifying $z_0=0$:
$\frac{\sin(z)}{z^3}=\frac{1}{z^3}\left(z-\frac{z^3}{3!}+\frac{z^5}{5!}-\frac{z^7}{7!}+...\right)=\frac{1}{z^2}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{z^2}{5!}-\frac{z^4}{7!}+...$
Hence $z_0$ is a pole of order 2.
Classifying $z_1=-2$:
$\frac{1}{(2+z)}$ so $(2+z)$ is a pole of order 1.
Please let me know where to improve or if these steps are incorrect I would be very appreciative if someone would be able to provide me with the correct ones, as I've done research but I'm still struggling to find a structured way to do it.
